# помогите с блоком CSS HTML

Tags: html, css3

есть блок DIV в котором четрые Р (параграфа) как сделать так, чтоб был виден один параграф, и кнопка читать. Когда нажимаешь кнопку читать блок увеоличивается и показывает весь текст, при этом кнопка остается всегда в низу, и ЧИТАТЬ сменяется на ЗАКРЫТЬ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну решение было бы попроще, но мой таракан-экстрасенс говорит, что в будущем захочется добавить на страницу несколько таких блоков. Поэтому вот:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/Lz04tej9/)

```js
(function(){

let moo = document.getElementsByClassName('moo');
for(let i = 0; i < moo.length; i++){
  let bubu   = moo[i].getElementsByClassName('bubu');
  let toggle = moo[i].getElementsByClassName('toggle');
  toggle[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
    for(let u = 1; u < bubu.length; u++){
      bubu[u].classList.toggle('show');
    }
    /* Это дело ниже называется Тернарный Оператор (можете искать статьи) */
    this.innerText = ( this.innerText == 'Читать далее...' ) ? ('Скрыть') : ( 'Читать далее...' );
  });
}

})();
```

```css
.bubu {display: none;}
.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="moo">
  <p class="bubu show">параграф 1</p>
  <p class="bubu">параграф 2</p>
  <p class="bubu">параграф 3</p>
  <p class="bubu">параграф 4</p>
  <button class="toggle">Читать далее...</button>
</div>

<div class="moo">
  <p class="bubu show">параграф 1</p>
  <p class="bubu">параграф 2</p>
  <p class="bubu">параграф 3</p>
  <p class="bubu">параграф 4</p>
  <button class="toggle">Читать далее...</button>
</div>
```

Это можно организовать и через label - чекбоксы на CSS... Но меня напрягает вечно думать о разметке, чтобы селекторы правильно сработали)

На CSS будет так:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/zhvk8o6g/)

```css
.hidden {display: none;}
.show {display: inline-block;}

.check {display: none;}
.check:checked ~ .hidden {display: block;}
.check:checked ~ label .show {display: none;}
.check:checked ~ label .hidden {display: inline-block;}

.btn {
  background-color: #045acf;
  color: white; padding: 3px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px; cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="moo">
  <input id="check1" class="check" type="checkbox">
  <p>параграф 1</p>
  <span class="hidden">
    <p>параграф 2</p>
    <p>параграф 3</p>
    <p>параграф 4</p>
  </span>
  <label for="check1">
    <span class="btn show">Читать далее...</span>
    <span class="btn hidden">Скрыть</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="moo">
  <input id="check2" class="check" type="checkbox">
  <p>параграф 1</p>
  <span class="hidden">
    <p>параграф 2</p>
    <p>параграф 3</p>
    <p>параграф 4</p>
  </span>
  <label for="check2">
    <span class="btn show">Читать далее...</span>
    <span class="btn hidden">Скрыть</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

С JS как-то попроще чтоли с разметкой... один раз написать скрипт - дальше добавлять этих блоков сколько захочется...

Comment: Из вопроса же очевидно, что спрашивает новичок. Чего Вы ему тут навертели? JS даже я с ходу не пойму что как работает, это раз. `let` не все браузеры поддерживают, новичок об это потенциально споткнётся, это два. И три - почему Вы ему схему электрического веника не нарисовали? Вдруг ваш таракан-экстрасенс подскажет ему что тараканов из головы надо выметать иногда? Это вот характерная черта обитателей русского StackOwerflow - спросишь какую-то элементарщину на три строчки, тебе распишут на шесть экранов листинга с ворохом сторонних библиотек такие вот экстрасенсы.. мамкины.

Comment: @Капитан Флинт сомневаюсь, что будет разумно в каждом ответе учить всех JS 'с нуля' )) В конце концов можно взять и по очереди гуглить все незнакомые слова в скрипте... Если аффтару реально интересно - записал отдельно объяснения... настолько подробно, насколько это возможно https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/qjmxpdkn/))

Comment: @КапитанФлинт , уважаемый, если у вас имеются какие-то претензии к автору ответа, пожалуйста напишите свой ответ как вы считаете нужным. Задача была выполнена и на вопрос был дан ответ. Вы же просто раскритиковали тип переменной и ничего более. Автор показал два варианта решения: с использование JS, с использованием CSS, какие могут быть проблемы? Будьте сдержаннее немного, если вам что-то могло не понравится, будьте добры оставить ответ с пояснениями так, как вы считаете это нужным.

Answer (score 0):

Создаёшь блок `<div>`, внутри четыре тэга `<p>` и кнопку. Последние три `<p>` прячешь в `<span>`, у которого по-умолчанию выставляешь `display: none`. Долго писать, короче, сообразишь :) Вот так:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '.more', function() {
        $('.hidden').show();
        $(this).addClass('close');
        $(this).removeClass('more');
        $(this).text('Закрыть');
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.close', function() {
        $('.wrapper').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>
        Параграф 1
    </p>
    <span class="hidden">
        <p>
            Параграф 2
        </p>
        <p>
            Параграф 3
        </p>
        <p>
            Параграф 4
        </p>
    </span>
    <button class="more">Читать дальше</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.toggle', function(){

    var post = $(this).parent('.post');
    // var post = $('.post');
    
    if(post.hasClass('show')){
      post.removeClass('show');
      $(this).html('Развернуть..');
    }
    else{
     post.addClass('show');
      $(this).html('Свернуть..');
    }
    
    
});

$(document).on('click', '.toggle-arrow', function(){
    
    var post = $(this).parent('.post');
    // var post = $('.post');
    
    post.toggleClass('show');
    
    
});
```

```css
.post{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.post p:not(:first-child){
  display: none;
}
.post.show p:not(:first-child){
  display: block;
}


.post .toggle-arrow{
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}
.post.show .toggle-arrow{
  transform: rotateZ(0deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post">
  <p>параграф 1</p>
  <p>параграф 2</p>
  <p>параграф 3</p>
  <p>параграф 4</p>
  <button class="toggle">Развернуть..</button>
</div>

<div class="post">
  <p>параграф 1</p>
  <p>параграф 2</p>
  <p>параграф 3</p>
  <p>параграф 4</p>
  <button class="toggle-arrow">^</button>
</div>
```

Не знаю почему, но какое-то отвращение менять значения или делать анимацию на стороне JS используя какие-то методы, больше люблю менять классы и в зависимости от этого делать анимацию, собственно вот сам код в двух вариациях.

**$(this).parent('.post');**

Эта строка берёт контейнер относительно кнопки, по которой произошёл клик. Если у вас будет несколько подобных элементов, то советую делать именно так, в ином случае у вас одна кнопка будет срабатывать на все сопутствующие классы.